# find the value of a key in a JSON without knowing the structure in advance

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JavaScript data structure. `a[]` is an array with text strings as elements. It is not 
    known in advance what it contains. For example,

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"...];
```

`res{}` is a JSON object with as many keys as elements in "a" with the following rule; the <strike>last</strike> innermost key of `res{}` is an object with 
    an array called `features[]` or the <strike>last</strike> innermost key itself is an array. So, if , then `res` is either

```
// if
a = ["foo", "bar"];

// then
res = {
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "features": []
        }
    }
};

// and I want
data = res["foo"]["bar"].features;

// or
res = {
    "foo": {
        "bar": []
    }
};

// and I want
data = res["foo"]["bar"];
```

As I said, it is not know in advance how long `a[]` is or what the values of its elements is. How can I do the above?

**Update:** fixed a typo in the structure of `res`

Comment: `res = {"foo": "bar": ...` is invalid JSON. Also, there's no "last" key in a JSON object; key order is not guaranteed (in fact, JSON objects are explicitly unordered).

Comment: fixed a typo, and changed "last" to "innermost"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works ok

```
function getFeatures(obj, keys) {
  if( keys.length ) {
    key = keys.shift();
    obj = obj[key];
    return getFeatures(obj, keys);
  } else {
    return obj.features || obj;
  }
}
```

You may want to call it with a copy of the keys-array, as the function shifts elements off of the array it's passed. I.e.

```
var keys = ["foo", "bar"];

var res1  = { "foo": { "bar": { "features": [1, 2, 3] } } };
getFeatures(res1, keys.slice(0)); // => [1, 2, 3]

var res2 = { "foo": { "bar": ["a", "b", "c"] } };
getFeatures(res2, keys.slice(0)); // => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. More than anything, a nice lesson in JS programming.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following recursive solution achieves your purpose.

```
function doSomething(i) {
    if (i==a.length)
        return []; // can be made {features:[]}
    var d = {}
    d[a[i]] = doSomething(i+1);
    return d;
}

doSomething(0);
```

Alternative iterative solution with initial set to features:

```
var a = ['foo', 'bar'];

var i = a.length -1;
var res,d={features:[]};

while(i >=0) {
    res ={};
    res[a[i]]=d;
    d=res;
    i--;
}
```

--V